# Convert Named Character Vector to data.frame

Tags: r, dataframe, vector, type-conversion

I have a named character vector returned from xmlAttrs like this:

```
testVect <- structure(c("11.2.0.3.0", "12.89", "12.71"), .Names = c("db_version", 
             "elapsed_time", "cpu_time"))
```

I would like to convert it to a data frame that looks like this:

```
testDF <- data.frame("db_version"="11.2.0.3.0","elapsed_time"=12.89,"cpu_time"=12.71)
head(testDF)
  db_version elapsed_time cpu_time
1 11.2.0.3.0        12.89    12.71
```

Answer (score 103, accepted):

It's as simple as `data.frame(as.list(testVect))`. Or if you want sensible data types for your columns, `data.frame(lapply(testVect, type.convert), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)`.

Comment: Oddly, the **tibble** analog of this does not work: `data_frame(as.list(testVect))` return a 5 row data frame.

Comment: @Deleet **tibble** will work with `as_tibble(as.list(testVect))` or `as_data_frame(as.list(testVect))` (`as_data_frame` is an alias for `as_tibble`).

Comment: In line with comments by @Deleet and @JWillliman, `data.table(as.list(...))` does not work, but instead `as.data.table(as.list(...))` does.

Comment: @Matthew Plourde Whether stringsAsFactors True or False, it gives the same data type. How to not change the data type?

Answer (score 76):

The answers from @MatthewPlourde and @JackRyan work, but if you have a long named vector it is annoying to have a data frame with one row and many columns.  If you'd rather have a "key" column and a "value" column with many rows, any of the following should work:

```
data.frame(keyName=names(testVect), value=testVect, row.names=NULL)

##        keyName      value
## 1   db_version 11.2.0.3.0
## 2 elapsed_time      12.89
## 3     cpu_time      12.71


## Suggested by @JWilliman
tibble::enframe(testVect)

## # A tibble: 3 x 2
##   name         value
##   <chr>        <chr>
## 1 db_version   11.2.0.3.0
## 2 elapsed_time 12.89
## 3 cpu_time     12.71


## Suggested by @Joe
stack(testVect)
##       values          ind
## 1 11.2.0.3.0   db_version
## 2      12.89 elapsed_time
## 3      12.71     cpu_time
```

Comment: sad that there's no one-liner

Comment: Can also use `tibble::enframe(testVect)`.

Comment: `stack(testVect)` also does this but leaves the values as characters.

Comment: @Jelena-bioinf as one-liner with dplyr syntax, you can use `testVect %>% as.list %>% as.data.frame %>% tidyr::gather()` This actually produces the 'key' and 'value' columns which @dnlbrky referred to.

Comment: `stack()`, what an underrated function!

Comment: Thank you, that was sueful!

Comment: stack is amazing, but it fails when your vector is not a vector ... ;) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72398317/stack-is-failing-on-date-vectors/72398318#72398318

Answer (score 22):

I'm going to take a stab at this:

```
test.vector <- as.data.frame(t(testVect))
class(test.vector)
```

Comment: Or even shorter, simply `data.frame(t(testVect))`

Answer (score 9):

I used to use the functions suggested in these answers (`as.list`, `as_tibble`, `t`, `enframe`, etc.) but have since found out that `dplyr::bind_rows` now works to do exactly what the original question asks with a single function call.

```r
library(dplyr)
testVect <- structure(c("11.2.0.3.0", "12.89", "12.71"), .Names = c("db_version", "elapsed_time", "cpu_time"))
testVect %>% bind_rows
#> # A tibble: 1 x 3
#>   db_version elapsed_time cpu_time
#>   <chr>      <chr>        <chr>   
#> 1 11.2.0.3.0 12.89        12.71
```

<sup>Created on 2019-11-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

As shown in [tidyverse - prefered way to turn a named vector into a data.frame/tibble](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40036207/tidyverse-prefered-way-to-turn-a-named-vector-into-a-data-frame-tibble)

Answer (score 4):

```
named vector %>% as_tibble(.,rownames="column name of row.names")
```

Comment: Please add some explanation around here so everybody can learn. As of now a one-liner is a bit shallow.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example using `tibble`:

`named_vector_df = tibble(name = names(named_vector), value = named_vector)`

Comment: Note to novices like me: this creates a df with 2 columns, one named "name" (with names as data, not row.names) and one named "value". I understand that OP meant precisely this but I came here searching for another but similar problem and spent a long time trying to figure out why this method produced strange results...