# tidyverse - prefered way to turn a named vector into a data.frame/tibble

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr, purrr, tidyverse

Using the `tidyverse` a lot i often face the challenge of turning named vectors into a `data.frame`/`tibble` with the columns being the names of the vector.
**What is the prefered/tidyversey way of doing this?**
EDIT: This is related to: [this](https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/issues/1676) and [this](https://github.com/hadley/purrr/issues/255) github-issue

So i want:

```
require(tidyverse)
vec <- c("a" = 1, "b" = 2)
```

to become this:

```
# A tibble: 1 × 2
      a     b
  <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     2
```

I can do this via e.g.:

```
vec %>% enframe %>% spread(name, value)
vec %>% t %>% as_tibble
```

Usecase example:

```
require(tidyverse)
require(rvest)
txt <- c('<node a="1" b="2"></node>',
         '<node a="1" c="3"></node>')

txt %>% map(read_xml) %>% map(xml_attrs) %>% map_df(~t(.) %>% as_tibble)
```

Which gives

```
# A tibble: 2 × 3
      a     b     c
  <chr> <chr> <chr>
1     1     2  <NA>
2     1  <NA>     3
```

Comment: what exactly, if anything, do you think is lacking about what you are doing(?)

Comment: I asked myself the same, because `bind_rows` does not work instead of `map_df(~t(.) %>% as_tibble)`. So, until now, I transpose, convert to a data frame with strings staying characters (not factors), and then bind the results together. However, a shortcut for this common task could be nice.

Comment: @lukeA, I think `bind_rows` has been updated to now work in the way you want

Answer (score 32, accepted):

This is now directly supported using `bind_rows` (introduced in `dplyr 0.7.0`):

```r
library(tidyverse)) 
vec <- c("a" = 1, "b" = 2)

bind_rows(vec)
#> # A tibble: 1 x 2
#>       a     b
#>   <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     1     2
```

This quote from https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/news.html explains the change:

> `bind_rows()` and `bind_cols()` now accept vectors. They are treated as rows by the former and columns by the latter. Rows require inner names like `c(col1 = 1, col2 = 2)`, while columns require outer names: `col1 = c(1, 2)`. Lists are still treated as data frames but can be spliced explicitly with `!!!`, e.g. `bind_rows(!!! x)` (#1676).

With this change, it means that the following line in the use case example:

`txt %>% map(read_xml) %>% map(xml_attrs) %>% map_df(~t(.) %>% as_tibble)`

can be rewritten as

`txt %>% map(read_xml) %>% map(xml_attrs) %>% map_df(bind_rows)`

which is also equivalent to

`txt %>% map(read_xml) %>% map(xml_attrs) %>% { bind_rows(!!! .) }`

The equivalence of the different approaches is demonstrated in the following example:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(rvest)

txt <- c('<node a="1" b="2"></node>',
         '<node a="1" c="3"></node>')

temp <- txt %>% map(read_xml) %>% map(xml_attrs)

# x, y, and z are identical
x <- temp %>% map_df(~t(.) %>% as_tibble)
y <- temp %>% map_df(bind_rows)
z <- bind_rows(!!! temp)

identical(x, y)
#> [1] TRUE
identical(y, z)
#> [1] TRUE

z
#> # A tibble: 2 x 3
#>       a     b     c
#>   <chr> <chr> <chr>
#> 1     1     2  <NA>
#> 2     1  <NA>     3
```

Comment: I am a bit confused by the distinction between setting *inner names* and *outer names* that you quote. See my question here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/67010860/5535152

Answer (score 7):

The idiomatic way would be to splice the vector with `!!!` within a `tibble()` call so the named vector elements become column definitions :

```r
library(tibble)
vec <- c("a" = 1, "b" = 2)
tibble(!!!vec)
#> # A tibble: 1 x 2
#>       a     b
#>   <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     1     2
```

<sup>Created on 2019-09-14 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

This works for me: `c("a" = 1, "b" = 2) %>% t() %>% tbl_df()`

Answer (score 1):

Interestingly you can use the `as_tibble()` method for lists to do this in one call. Note that this isn't best practice since this isn't an exported method.

```
tibble:::as_tibble.list(vec)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
as_tibble(as.list(c(a=1, b=2)))
```