# Tidyverse: how to bind together two column vectors

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I am trying to bind together the two following vectors:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(mvtnorm)

x.points <- seq(-3, 3, length.out = 100)
y.points <- seq(-3, 3, length.out = 100)
```

I can do it easily in base R:

```r
data1 <- cbind(x.points, y.points) 
head(data1)
#>       x.points  y.points
#> [1,] -3.000000 -3.000000
#> [2,] -2.939394 -2.939394
#> [3,] -2.878788 -2.878788
#> [4,] -2.818182 -2.818182
#> [5,] -2.757576 -2.757576
#> [6,] -2.696970 -2.696970
```

I have tried using dplyr following the suggestion [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46287853/5535152) but it did not work that well:

```r
data2 <- bind_cols(x.points, y.points, c("x","y"))

#> Error: Can't recycle `..1` (size 100) to match `..3` (size 2).
```

I am confused about the difference between setting up "inner names" and "outer names" mentioned in the answer linked above: "Rows require inner names like `c(col1 = 1, col2 = 2)`, while columns require `outer names: col1 = c(1, 2)`."

<sup>Created on 2021-04-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: `bind_cols(x.points, y.points)`. It looks like you didn't run `library(dplyr)` first.

Comment: did you load the dplyr package with `library(dplyr)`? does `dplyr::bind_cols` work?

Comment: @Matt I have edited the question, there was a mistake in the reprex (like everybody noticed, I had forgotten to include the libraries in selection.) Once that error is fixed, there is a different error popping up, related to the way I was trying to rename the columns.

Comment: Not sure if you still need clarification, but as I did in my answer, the outer name `x` for the column is outside the vector defining the column `x.points`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It actually works, just don't forget when you use the `reprex` package to include the libraries (here `dplyr`)

```r
library(dplyr)
x.points <- seq(-3, 3, length.out = 100)
y.points <- seq(-3, 3, length.out = 100)
data2 <- bind_cols(x=x.points, y=y.points)
data2
#> # A tibble: 100 x 2
#>        x     y
#>    <dbl> <dbl>
#>  1 -3    -3   
#>  2 -2.94 -2.94
#>  3 -2.88 -2.88
#>  4 -2.82 -2.82
#>  5 -2.76 -2.76
#>  6 -2.70 -2.70
#>  7 -2.64 -2.64
#>  8 -2.58 -2.58
#>  9 -2.52 -2.52
#> 10 -2.45 -2.45
#> # ... with 90 more rows
```

Comment: I have edited the question, there was a mistake in the reprex (like everybody noticed, I had forgotten to include the libraries in selection.) Once that error is fixed, there is a different error popping up, related to the way I was trying to rename the columns. I was confused about the difference between setting up 'inner names' and `outer names` in `bind_rows` and `bind_cols` respectively.